# Read and Display matrix

Tags: c

I'm having a small issue with this problem and I could really use another set of eyes with this. I am basically trying to read a matrix that I input and then display the said matrix.

The program always returns a null matrix (0 on all positions). The size of the matrix (columns/rows) is good. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXN 10

void display_matrix(int n, int m, double a[MAXN][MAXN], char ch)
{
    int i, j;

    printf("\n MATRIX %c\n", ch);
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < m; j++) printf("%8.2lf ",a[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void read_matrix(int *n, int *m, double a[MAXN][MAXN])
{
     int i,j;
     printf("\nInput of size and elements of a matrix\n");
     printf("\n\tNumber of rows, n=");
     scanf("%d", n);
     printf("\n\tNumber of columns, m=");
     scanf("%d", m);
     printf("\n\tThe elements of the matrix\n");
     for (i = 0; i < *n; i++)
     {
         for(j = 0; j < *m; j++)
         {
            printf("a[%d,%d]=", i, j);
            scanf("%lf",&a[i][j]);
         }
     }
     printf("\n");
}

void main()
{
    int n, m;
    double a[MAXN][MAXN];
    read_matrix(&n, &m, a);
    display_matrix(n, m, a, 'X');
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive. You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen. As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem. (And then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).)

Comment: Hello Oli Charlesworth, thanks for the fast comment and advice. I only post here as a last resort and when I really can't find my errors. I will take your advice though and I'm going to 'befriend' the debugger to help spot my errors. The link you provided will also be of much use.

Comment: What I can remember from C is you need to use a double pointer when passing arrays.

Comment: The type of main is void, you can't return a value. Even though, I tried it on MS Visual Studio 2013 and it works.

Comment: It works on gcc too. Also, your main should have the return type int, if you want to return 0, or don't return anything if you want to have it void. In order to be able to help you, you should give as some more details about your compiler, environment and so on.

Comment: Do enter a character that is not accepted when you enter a number? (e.g ,125 (for .125))

Comment: I'm using codeblocks with the gcc compiler. The programs runs fine, allows me to input number of rows/lines, and also allows me to input the elements of the matrix...but it always returns a null matrix (0 on all positions). Can you guys generate a matrix with other elements?

Comment: Yes it works fine, using codeblocks  & gcc(MinGW-4.8.1)

Comment: Working with the code on an Ubuntu 14.04 LTS derivative with GCC 4.8.2, I fixed some bloopers in the code (primarily `int main(void)`; it won't compile for me with the options I use) and adding an error check to each `scanf()`, the code worked for me correctly with a 3x5 matrix.  This is consistent with what other people reported — it works for them.  You should check that the array dimensions entered are valid.  Otherwise, it seems to work.  You might be running into a problem with the local `printf()` misinterpreting `%lf` format, as Nisse Engstrom suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems mostly fine (`main()` should have a return type of `int`, and you should always check the return value of `scanf()`), except possibly for the following line:

```
printf("%8.2lf ",a[i][j]);
```

Prior to the C99 standard, the `l` modifier was not defined in conjunction with the `f` conversion specifier. Using the two in combination resulted in *undefined behaviour*. I don't know what the odds are, but it is not inconceivable that you have a pre-C99 C library that either misbehaves or implements `%lf` to match something entirely different, perhaps `long double`.

To print a double, you should use the `%f` conversion specifier:

```
printf("%8.2f ",a[i][j]);
```

This is just clutching at straws though. It might not change anything at all for you.

#### Background

The `scanf()` function has different conversion specifiers for `float` (`%f`) and `double` (`%lf`), because it need to know the exact type that the corresponding pointer argument is pointing to.

But when you pass a `float` to a variadic function, such as `printf()`, the *default argument promotions* convert the `float` to a `double`. Hence, the `printf()` function does not need a conversion specifier for `float`, because there is no way to pass a `float` to it. The C99 standard added the `l` modifier just for symmetry with the `scanf()` function.

#### References

- The C90 Standard: [ISO/IEC 9899:1990](https://www.iso.org/standard/17782.html) (Withdrawn)
- The C99 Standard: [ISO/IEC 9899:1999](https://www.iso.org/standard/29237.html) (Withdrawn)
- The C11 Standard: [ISO/IEC 9899:2011](https://www.iso.org/standard/57853.html) (Withdrawn)
- The C18 Standard: [ISO/IEC 9899:2018](https://www.iso.org/standard/74528.html) (Current)

Comment: One issue you don't (yet) mention is checking that the `scanf()` operations all succeed.  Another good idea (especially if you have problems) is printing key data shortly after it is read, such as the dimensions of the matrix.  The code limits the matrix dimensions to `MAXN`; it should enforce that limit (and reject zero or negative dimensions too).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Excellent points. I got into a state of mind where I thought all the obvious problems had already been covered.